# jquery add a class and cycle it on the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set of list elements like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
<div class="prev">PREVIOUS</div>
<div class="next">NEXT</div>
```

I need to add a class `active` on the second and third li, and then when I click on the next button, those two classes will move by one down the list, to third and fourth list, until they reach the last li. Also when I click on previous button the classes would move up the lists.

So when my page loads I need to have this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
<div class="prev">PREVIOUS</div>
<div class="next">NEXT</div>
```

Then when I click on the next button this happens

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
<div class="prev">PREVIOUS</div>
<div class="next">NEXT</div>
```

And so on. I have this so far:

```
$(window).load( function(){

var ul = $('ul'),
    li = ul.find('li');

var $prev=$('prev');
var $next=$('next');

li.eq(1).addClass('active');
li.eq(2).addClass('active');

$next.on('click', function(){
    if(li.hasClass('active')){
        li.removeClass('active');
    }
////stuck    

});

});
```

I've tried just using `.next().addClass('active')`, but that just adds `active` class on all the list items, and I don't need that.

Also can I have some kind of delay between removing and adding the classes? I'm using this as a carousel. On next my whole unsorted list moves to the left some amount of pixels, and that works. I need to add classes so that I can have opacity lowered on all, except those with `active` class, so I need to have a smooth transition.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how about keeping a counter and using that to find the current 2 li remove the active class then find the next 2 li and add the active class? increment the count on next click and decrement on prev click. on next click -> li.removeClass("active"); li.eq(counter).addClass("active"); li.eq(counter+1).addClass("active"); counter++;

Comment: That's what I need in a nutshell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your selectors `$('prev')` and `$('next')` are trying to match elements with the tagnames `prev` and `next`. You mean `.prev` and `.next`, presumably.

Previous is easy, you simply need to `.filter()` your active list items, remove the class, traverse to the previous element, and add it back:

```
$prev.on('click', function(){
    li.filter('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
});
```

Next is (a little) trickier, since we need to reverse our jQuery object first:

```
$next.on('click', function(){
    $(li.get().reverse()).filter('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhdf3we5/)

Comment: You may want to check that the `.active` class is not at the beginning when clicking prev and at the end when clicking next. But I'll leave that to you :) Glad to have helped.

Comment: There is no need for your `$(li.get().reverse())`, it works just with the `li.filter` like in the `prev` event.

Answer (score 1):

Updated to make it also include the last and first li

Here is another way. You simple check if the *next* or *previous* element has the class *first* or *last* and don't change class if they do.

```js
var ul = $('ul'),
  li = ul.find('li');

var $prev = $('.prev');
var $next = $('.next');

li.eq(1).addClass('active');
li.eq(2).addClass('active');

$next.on('click', function() {
  var $a = $('.active');
  if (!$($a[0]).next().hasClass('last'))  // check if the first active li has next as last
       $a.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
});

$prev.on('click', function() {
  var $a = $('.active');
  if (!$($a[1]).prev().hasClass('first')) // check if the last active li has prev as first
       $a.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: lightblue !important;
}
.first,
.last {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
<div class="prev">PREVIOUS</div>
<div class="next">NEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y04ndk6z/) with your problem and my solution :)

Added following:

```
var pointer = 1;
```

fixed (a dot was missing):

```
var $prev=$('.prev');
var $next=$('.next');
```

Updated this:

```
li.eq(pointer).addClass('active');
li.eq(pointer+1).addClass('active');
```

And updated your prev/next:

```
$next.on('click', function(){
  if(li.hasClass('active')){
      li.removeClass('active');
  }
  pointer++;

  li.eq(pointer).addClass('active');
  li.eq(pointer+1).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var len = $('ul li').length;
    $('.prev').click(function(){
        if($('.active:first').index()!=0)
        {   
         $('.active').each(function(){            
            $(this).removeClass('active').prev('li').addClass('active');
        });
        }
    });

    $('.next').click(function(){
        if($('.active:last').index()!=(len - 1))
        {
          $('.active').each(function(){

          $(this).next('li').addClass('active');
        });
            $('.active:first').removeClass('active');    
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d2kjgr2w/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way

```
var ul = $('ul'),
    li = ul.find('li');

var $prev=$('.prev');
var $next=$('.next');

li.eq(1).addClass('active');
li.eq(2).addClass('active');

$next.on('click', function(){
    var lil = $("li.active:last").not(".last");
    lil.prev().toggleClass("active");
    lil.next().toggleClass("active");
});
$prev.on('click', function(){
    var lil = $("li.active:first").not(".first");
    lil.prev().toggleClass("active");
    lil.next().toggleClass("active");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/098p4fLa/